# Program Freeze: Adding Array Elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a solution, but not the one I want. Here's the code:

```
def sum(nums)
idx = 0

while idx < nums.length
    nums[idx] = idx * nums[idx]

    idx += 1
end

print nums   

idx2 = 0
idx3 = idx2 + 1
while idx3 < nums.length
    result = (nums[idx2].to_i) + (nums[idx3].to_i)

    idx2 += 1
end

puts result
end

sum([2,3])
sum([2,3,5])
sum([2,3,5,2])
```

Two things I don't understand are happening at the second `while` loop. First, if I use `while idx2 < nums.length` I get some unusual addition (the array sums come back as 6, 13, 9). If I use `while idx3 < nums.length` the program will not run all the way through. It stops at line 14 (at the 2nd loop), where I must interupt it with `Ctrl+C`.

I'm sure I'm just not understanding what's going on here so I'm asking for help.

**I also realize I can use `inject` and `each` loops for a simpler sum solution (and map and procs/blocks and other objects).** I'm trying to understand how these things work, not just come up with a solution.

Comment: It helps to say what your program is meant to accomplish, and to give examples of inputs and the corresponding outputs you want...

Answer (score 1):

```
idx3 < nums.length
```

Will be always true because you aren't changing neither of those values, so the right will stay bigger than the left and your loop never ends.

Using the other condition instead, will result in something that I cannot predict without knowing what nums is, but probably is not what you expect since you're overwriting the value you had stored on result, so only the last iteration will make something noticeable.

There is no array sums I can see here :S

I suggest you try to simply your program and test one concept at a time. If you test all of them at once you won't know what is causing what.

Comment: As mentioned above, idx3 is supposed to increment when idx2 is incremented. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Proto No, that's not the case. When you say that you want idx2 to be equal to idx3 + 1, you're only copying the value idx3 + 1 and storing it into idx2. After that each variable follows it's own path, to relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

In your second while loop you are not incrementing idx3.  Thus idx3 never reaches num.length, and you have yourself an infinite loop.

Comment: That shouldn't be true. idx2 is incremented on every pass, which automatically increments idx3. Or at least that's what I thought would happen. Is that not the case?

Comment: You need to move `idx3 = idx2 + 1` into the `while` loop (right before `result =...`, but you don't need `idx3`: `result = (nums[idx2].to_i) + (nums[idx2+1].to_i)`. I haven't gone through the rest of your code, so I don't know if this change is enough.